# Mounting OverlayFS in fstab at startup

Tags: systemd, fstab, embedded, overlayfs

Is It possible to Mount OverlayFS from external partition in fstab and benefit from systemd services extensions at startup ? Thus overlay directory tree will add new systemd services configuration defined from another disk partition.
For example, if I need to update new network configuration settings can I use this solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.  As far as I know systemd doesn't support mounting something from `/etc/fstab` and then reloading unit files. *Others may know a way that I don't!*. However there's one file system which isn't necessarily loaded by systemd and that's the root filesystem mounted at `/`.

At least initially, `/` is mounted by [initramfs](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/initramfs.html).  Initramfs contains scripts and a shell (usually [busybox](https://busybox.net/)) enough to find and mount `/`.  It is responsible for interpreting the [kernel parameter `root=`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bootparam.7.html).

Most distributions provide a way to add additional scripts (hooks) to initramfs and these will usually offer at least one hook which can be used to completely change `/` before the stock scripts call [pivot_root](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pivot_root.2.html).

This way you can write your own script to take the `root=` mount point and make it the top layer of an overlayfs which is then what initramfs will convert into `/`.

You've not listed a distribution so it would be impossible for me to give a step by step guide.  But hopefully that's enough to get you on the right track.

Comment: I found this for my custom Linux distro and It seems It may do the trick : https://github.com/cmhe/meta-readonly-rootfs-overlay